# Trying to search data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to implement a search bar to my app i get this error under `empList.setAdapter(adapter)`
the error is `error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)`
why this error occurs this is how the method looks like

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                ArrayList<String> empList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String emp : list){
                    if (emp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                        empList.add(emp);
                    }
                }


                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewEmployee.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, empList);
                empList.setAdapter(adapter);

                return true;
            }
        });


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: you are setting adapter on arraylist of string not on listview or recyclerview thatswhy

Comment: It should be. Listview Or recyclerview.setadapter(adapter).

Comment: it dosnt work @KishanMaurya